# How to hide password in API response?

Tags: python, django, django-models, password-protection

I know that some may say that there is no need to provide password in api-response if i have to hide it. but the point is, even if i go to admin section, i can see the password hash value, that's why i'm doing this.

So my question is, how can I hide that password in my API response. For ex. using asterisks.

**Note: I have a custom model for my data.**
**i just need a function and where to put it to work.**

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password


class MyUser(models.Model):
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    profile_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to="user_data/profile_picture", blank=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField(blank=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    contact = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    time_stamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.pk:
            self.password = make_password(self.password)
        super(MyUser, self).save()
```

Comment: Are you using django-rest-framework? can you show me your current view.py and where you make your response?

Comment: Thanks for paying your attention. now i already have made changes to my source code to fix these issues. Thanks again! Please keep up your contribution and  future help :)

Comment: Just put the password to write only in the Serializer                                     
  extra_kwargs = {
            'password': {'write_only': True}
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to override the **BaseUserManager, AbstractBaseUser** from django.contrib.auth.models to work with your custom model. Thus it will act as a default User model(built-in model) and it will do all. [Follow this link to the guide(Code)](https://www.codingforentrepreneurs.com/blog/how-to-create-a-custom-django-user-model/) or [Follow this link for step by step brief guide(video tutorial)](https://youtu.be/HshbjK1vDtY)

Answer (score 1):

You can provide any number of asterisks you like, or provide the hashed password (`user.password`). There is no way for you to know what a user's password is, or how many characters are in it, though, so providing somepassword as ************ (same number of characters) is not possible.

If you feel you need to provide *something*, I recommend just picking an arbitrary number of asterisks.

As an aside, I would strongly suggest you look at [the documentation for extending the Django User model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model), rather than fully rolling your own.